# Change fixed header logo while scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I need to change logo in fixed header while passing different sections.

If you take a look at [this](https://hawkemedia.com/) site, it changes color while scroll down. I need to have this function in my website. [This](http://bitmontrade.com/sample/papa/) is the site that I am working on right now.

Built with WordPress divi theme.

Tried new things but none of it is working. Can anyone recommend how to code this function?

I tried to use custom css inside divi module but it is not working.

I have this css code it was used for regular heading to sticking heading.

```css
#logo {
opacity:1;
display:inherit;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
#logo.second-logo {
opacity:0;
margin: 0 0 -200px -130px;
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.et-fixed-header #logo {
opacity: 0;
margin: -200px 0px 0 0px;
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
 
}
.et-fixed-header #logo.second-logo {
opacity:1;
margin: 0 0 0 -90px !important;
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

So, when user scroll down and passing different section this 
.et-fixed-header #logo 
.et-fixed-header #logo.second-logo

I want opacity change dynamically while scroll down and pass different section.

Comment: Please join css you are working one with a test page.

Comment: please share the css class you created for the header

Comment: i am sorry first time in stackoverflow. let me see if i can do that

Comment: @SebaCherian .et-fixed-header #logo.second-logo

Comment: apply style position: fixed; to the header class.

Comment: @SebaCherian i added more details into question see if that clears better for you.

Comment: @LeBigCat i think i did can you please review question one more time? thanks